# How to plot the ROC Curve and Accuracy using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, roc

From a dataframe consisting of va1, val1 and weight I created a training set and a test set. I used some metrics and compared them to the test set. The corresponding (true) values are saved inside the True_positive_df dataframe, while the non-matching values are saved inside the False_positive_df dataframe.

```
True_positive_df:

val1  val2  weight
123   345   67.09
453   256   43.51
...   ...   ...

False_positive_df:

val1  val2 weight
789   878 90.23
782   293  62.53 
...   ...  ...
```

I would like to create a ROC curve and calculate the accuracy of the calculation. How can I do this using the two dataframes?

I know that usually to create the ROC curve you need the parameters x and y like this one:

```
import scikitplot as skplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = # ground truth labels
y_probas = # predicted probabilities generated by sklearn classifier
skplt.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_true, y_probas)
plt.show()
```

with the data and the target, but it is not clear to me what I should plot exactly, what data to insert and which dataframe

Comment: Can you make sure to provide all the dataframe for a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Also, have you check the documentation of the [sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve.html) function? It lists all the parameters, the first 3 are mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the dataframes in your snippets you are dealing with a regression, not a classification problem. This means that you are not trying to predict classes of your observations, but specific values (the `weight` variable, I assume).
Because you are not trying to classify observations, measures like true positive or false positive rate are not well defined. As a result ROC curve cannot be created in the context of a regression problem.

You can find more information [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88920/how-to-create-roc-curve-to-assess-the-performance-of-regression-models).

Comment: I’m not really sure. I took a dataframe from which I removed 20% of the elements and tried to predict, with the remaining 80% the others. The weight represents the probability that that pair is there or not in the 20%. So I think it’s a classification... or am I wrong?

Comment: In this case I don't understand what your dataframe represents and what you are trying to predict. What do you mean that the "weight represents the probability that that pair is there or not in the 20%"? If by 20% you mean the test data - then given observation either is in the test data or not. But generally, if you used classification indeed then to plot the ROC curve you just need the true y labels and probabilistic output of your classifier.